# Azure Devops - Multi project kanban boards

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-boards

​**Context**:

I have an organization with multiple projects. Some projects use a tag to identify Epics and Features in scope where others use a relationship to a Strategic theme to identify the scope.

**ASK**:

I have been asked to setup two consolidated boards in Azure Devops that can show all Epics and Features. I've tried to use the query feature, but I can only identify Epics and features based on Strategic Theme in the "Tree of work item" query type where Boards are not supported.

Based on your experience is there a workaround to create consolidated boards based on Strategic Themes showing all associated child Epics or Features? Or do I need to use tagging + querying to achieve this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Use area paths.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid you have to use tagging and querying. If you just need to show all the Epics and Features in a board. You can check out [Query results](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/dashboards/widget-catalog?view=azure-devops#query-results) widget on the **Dashboards** under **Overview** in Devops project UI page.

You can create queries to query all the Epics and features based on Strategic Theme or tags. And display the query result on a widget on the Dashboards.